# AppendOnlyHistory duplicates comments sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-designer

TLDR I've used this code 
    `<SharePoint:AppendOnlyHistory runat="server" FieldName="PublishComments" ControlMode="Display" ItemId="{@ID}"/>`

To add a "Comments history" to a list. I've used sharepoint designer on a custom list. That code is for Item View, i've also added the one for edit.

My problem is that even if i create a new item, the history field will duplicate the comment. That also happens if i edit the item (the previous 2 comments show up in history and the new comment gets duplicated aswell so instead of 2 i've got 4 comments).
 I've searched online and i can't find anything relevant. Im using Multiple Lines of Text -> Enhanced riched text.

Any idea on how to fix the duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I found no way of fixing this in SharePoint so i did a workaround in jQuery (in case anyone needs it).

```
    $(".pubHistory div").each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        if (seen[txt]) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {
            seen[txt] = true;
        }
    });
```

pubHistory class is for the parent TR, the div selector is there because each comment is inside a div. It loops through the comments and removes duplicates.
I'll update this question if i ever find a way to fix it without jQuery.